# i have followed the documentation yet i got the error

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

i want to learn leaflet on react. i am a starter at react js / tailwind css and leaflet as well. but, i followed their official documentation and still got these error in setup ifself. Where did i did it wrong?

```
import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, useMap } from "react-leaflet";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div id="map" className="h-180px">
      <MapContainer center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
          <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

ERROR I got:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR

[eslint] 
src\App.tsx
  Line 13:10:  'Marker' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 14:12:  'Popup' is not defined   react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.


ERROR

[eslint] 
src\App.tsx
  Line 13:10:  'Marker' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 14:12:  'Popup' is not defined   react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.


ERROR in src/App.tsx:13:10

TS2304: Cannot find name 'Marker'.
    11 |           url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    12 |         />
  > 13 |         <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
       |          ^^^^^^
    14 |           <Popup>
    15 |             A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
    16 |           </Popup>


ERROR in src/App.tsx:14:12

TS2304: Cannot find name 'Popup'.
    12 |         />
    13 |         <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
  > 14 |           <Popup>
       |            ^^^^^
    15 |             A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
    16 |           </Popup>
    17 |         </Marker>


ERROR in src/App.tsx:16:13

TS2304: Cannot find name 'Popup'.
    14 |           <Popup>
    15 |             A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
  > 16 |           </Popup>
       |             ^^^^^
    17 |         </Marker>
    18 |       </MapContainer>
    19 |     </div>


ERROR in src/App.tsx:17:11

TS2304: Cannot find name 'Marker'.
    15 |             A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
    16 |           </Popup>
  > 17 |         </Marker>
       |           ^^^^^^
    18 |       </MapContainer>
    19 |     </div>
    20 |   );
```

i have added typescript, tailwind css and leaflet with the create-react-app.
(sorry if my question asking pattern is not correct. i am a newbie. help me P-l-e-a-s-e )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed importing `Marker` and `Popup` from `react-leaflet`. Try the code below.

```
import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, useMap, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div id="map" className="h-180px">
      <MapContainer center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
          <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but somehow I figured it out already and tried. now, the app runs but doesn't have any output. i have copied their dummy code, so it should have worked, right? all the codes are the same and still the output is Blank,  why? how can I get the required output? ( Checked youtube too, there the output is showing the map but in my device its blank (with exact same code)).

Comment: You might have missed importing this App.js file in the index file or please check the inspect if any js error displaying.

Comment: hi, i have included the app.js file in the index. No errors are shown. terminal says, You can now view leaflet in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000        
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.101.8:3000    

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build. 

webpack compiled successfully
No issues found.   AND in problems it shows, No problem have been detected in the workspace.

Comment: if it is still not displaying the map. Can you host your code somewhere and share the link?

Comment: ho, thanks but it worked !